# REST API JSON response in POSTMAN: one field is coming as null in response

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jpa

I am saving this entity using JPA in DERBY DB, whenever I am posting JSON and trying to save data in DB, my url field is coming null in response, while insertion of data is going well and I am not getting any error.

POJO class:

```
@Entity
public class Message {



@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long id;
private String title;
private String content;
private String sender;
private String URL;

public Message(){
    
}



public Message(String URL,Long id ,String title, String content, String sender) {
    super();
    this.URL = URL;
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.content = content;
    this.sender = sender;
}



public String getURL() {
    return URL;
}

public void setURL(String uRL) {
    URL = uRL;
}

@JsonIgnore
@JsonProperty(value = "id")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getSender() {
    return sender;
}

public void setSender(String sender) {
    this.sender = sender;
}




}
```

post JSON:

```
{
    "title":"alpha beta gama",
    "content":"greek letters" ,
    "sender":"laura",
    "URL":"http://abc.efg"
}
```

Response

```
{
    "title": "alpha beta gama",
    "content": "greek letters",
    "sender": "laura",
    "url": null
}
```

Comment: What is the request handling framework, spring-web-MVC , Spring Boot, etc ..?

Comment: i am using spring-boot

Comment: private String URL; is the issue, Always consider about JPA entity naming conventions

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to user lowercase "url" instead of "URL"?

Comment: actually it worked but i wonder why it just a name ,what matters if it is URL or url.